# Is there a better way to write it?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I'm writting something. However I'm not good at English writting.

Suppose that $X=D^\mathfrak c$. 
I want to express this :

> Let $x$ be the
>   unique point of $X$ such that $x(\gamma)=1$ and for any other $\alpha <
> \mathfrak c$, $x(\alpha)=0$.

Is there a better way to write it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write almost what you have written, but change the order at the end, so the sentence would read:

> Let $x$ be the unique point of $X$ such that both $x(\gamma)=1$ and $x(\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$ with $\alpha \neq \gamma$.

Comment: The last sentence is best put as a (polite) comment in the post.

Comment: Ah, you're right, @Peter.  Paul, no disrespect intended.

Comment: _not_ for any $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$, but for all $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$ with $\alpha \neq \gamma$. Or else you'd define $x(\gamma) $ to be $0$ and $1$ at the same time!

Comment: Fixed to reflect both comments.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can legitimately avoid having to write much English at all:

> Define $x\in X$ by $$x(\xi)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }\xi=\gamma\\0,&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a list using enumerate.

Let $x$ be the unique point of $X$ such that:

1. $x(\gamma)=1$, and
2. For any $\alpha<\mathfrak c$, $x(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Thnaks for your recomment. But I hope that i can write it in a sentence, because I used it in a proof.

Comment: @Paul: You can write the suggestion of this answer verbatim in a proof; there's nothing wrong with it and in fact it's better than your original formulation.